# Set ImageView size before the image is downloaded

Tags: android, imageview

I want to reproduce the image loading found in Google Plus Android app or in 9gag Android App where the image is not downloaded yet, but the `ImageView` already has the width and height. I thought about sending the dimensions with the `URL` like

```
{"image":{"url":"http://someurl.com/withanimage.jpg","width":"500","height":"300"}}
```

And then using that width and height to set a size to the `ImageView` before the image is downloaded, but the thing is that Android has many different sizes of screen and DPI that I don't really find a way to do this. Any help would be appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short [answer](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/blob/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/ImageLoader.java) see 'decodeFile()' that calls BitmapFactory.decode 2X. First time just to get the bounds of the file which you can compare to the available pixels on the device, producing mediated BitmapImage size as below:

```
   public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {              
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;

...

options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels);

bmp_larg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uris[0]),  null,  options);
```

Long [answer](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/ImageLoaderConfiguration.java) spend time on this project looking how the ImageLoader is configured depending on the device.